# Calculate group percentage to 2 decimal places - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting, decimal, number-formatting

I have the following query:

```
SELECT hostVersion, CONVERT(varchar, 100.0 * count(*) / tot,1)  + '%' as 'Percent'
FROM hostInfo,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as tot FROM hostInfo) x
GROUP BY hostVersion, tot
```

And receive the following output:

```
+--------------------------------+
| hostVersion | Percent          |
+--------------------------------+
|    5.0.0    | 26.666666666666% |
+--------------------------------+
|    5.1.0    | 73.333333333333% |
+--------------------------------+
```

How to I round to only 1 decimal place? (i.e. 26.7% & 73.3%)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better choice for conversion is the `str()` function.  (Documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx).)

In addition, you can do your calculation using window functions (assuming that you are using SQL Server 2005 or more recent).  Here is my version of the query:

```
select hi.hostVersion,
       str(((100.0*count(*)) / sum(count(*)) over ()), 5, 2)+'%'
from hostInfo hi
group by hi.hostVersion
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
CAST(ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(*) / tot, 1) AS DECIMAL(10, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT hostVersion, CONVERT(varchar, ROUND(100.0 * count(*) / tot,2),1)  + '%' as 'Percent'
FROM hostInfo,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as tot FROM hostInfo) x
GROUP BY hostVersion, tot
```